# My connection is closed after connecting to server via SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, debian, ubuntu-18.04, plesk

I Clash to big problem for me.

I have vPS on Hetzner with ubuntu OS and plesk. I have shared hosting for some specific websites for my companie. When I want to connect to the domain name via ssh I'm getting this error:

```
system informacion : 
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Plesk Obsidian
Version 18.0.32 Update #2



domain@domain.ge's password: passswod

Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-126-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
 * Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
 * Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
https://ubuntu.com/livepatch
New release '20.04.1 LTS' available.
 *Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: day/time from ip
Connection to domain closed.
```

Comment: There is no error...

Comment: and what is this then? can u tell me? normal? how i should fix this. im using ubuntu for plesk so i can't upgrade to 24.04 i should use 18. how i can fix it?

Comment: The first comment meant it looked like you hadn't posted the error message. But I think everything that follows "I'm getting this error" is the message from the server. I edited the question accordingly, please review and correct me ([edit]) if needed.

Comment: as your ssh connection is able to being established and then kicks you out, this seem to be needed to be troubleshooted on the server side, but what you could try is to `ssh -vvv <user@domain.ge>` it might give you some insight why it is dropped. have you only one user which you can use?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running in a shared hosting environment, it's likely that the system is configured not to let you have a shell, although some remote commands might be able to be executed.  Usually this is so that folks can use things like SFTP or push data via Git but not otherwise execute arbitrary commands.

You can verify this with `ssh -vvv domain@domain.ge`, which will show you whether the shell request was allowed or denied.  Even if the shell request was allowed, it might be that your shell is set to something like `/bin/false` or a wrapper program which only allows certain programs, which would result in this behavior.

If you have questions about this, I'd ask your hosting provider, or, if you host the entire thing yourself, investigate the Plesk manual to see how to enable shell access.